# Selecting specific row number in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is any way that I could select specified number of row in SQL Server? 
here i have the query   the Result looking like this

```
select LEFT(intValue,patindex('%$*%' , intValue) -1) as ID,
   Right(intValue, (LEN(intValue) - (patindex('%$*%' , intValue) + 1)))as Data  
   from dbo.Split('1$*hi,2$*hellow, ',')

ID  |   Data
----------------
 1  |   HI  
 2  |   hellow
```

here i  i wan to select the specific row item Data

```
select LEFT(intValue,patindex('%$*%' , intValue) -1) as ID,
   Right(intValue, (LEN(intValue) - (patindex('%$*%' , intValue) + 1)))as Data  
   from dbo.Split('1$*hi,2$*hellow, ',') ID=1
```

like where ID=1

I need Result like

```
Data
-----
 HI
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select Right(intValue, (LEN(intValue) - (patindex('%$*%' , intValue) + 1)))as Data

from dbo.Split('1$*hi,2$*hellow,3$*Acronym', ',') 
where LEFT(intValue,patindex('%$*%' , intValue) -1)  = 1`

Comment: Thanks for Replay MayOkaba it's working for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
With CTE As (
select LEFT(intValue,patindex('%$*%' , intValue) -1) as ID,
   Right(intValue, (LEN(intValue) - (patindex('%$*%' , intValue) + 1)))as Data  
   from dbo.Split('1$*hi,2$*hellow, ',')
)
Select * From CTE Where ID = 1
```